# FBX UV Coordinates is strange

Tags: fbx

i want correct UV Coordinates model
likes this model[image]

but Model load and render at my importer result is likes this
[image]

My fbx uv coordinates extract code is here

```
     FbxLayerElementUV* layerUVs = pMesh->GetLayer(0)->GetUVs();
                if (NULL != layerUVs)
                {
                    int uvIndex = 0;
                    FbxLayerElement::EReferenceMode referenceMode = layerUVs->GetReferenceMode();
                    FbxLayerElement::EMappingMode mappingMode = layerUVs->GetMappingMode();

                    if (FbxLayerElement::eByPolygonVertex == mappingMode)
                    {
                        int id = pMesh->GetTextureUVIndex(j, k);
                        if (FbxLayerElement::eDirect == referenceMode ||
                            FbxLayerElement::eIndexToDirect == referenceMode)
                            uvIndex = id;
                    }
                    else if (FbxLayerElement::eByControlPoint == mappingMode)
                    {
                        if (FbxLayerElement::eDirect == referenceMode) uvIndex = iControlPointIndex;
                        else if (FbxLayerElement::eIndexToDirect == referenceMode)
                            uvIndex = layerUVs->GetIndexArray().GetAt(iControlPointIndex);
                    }
        FbxVector2 uv = layerUVs->GetDirectArray()[uvIndex];

        vtx.u = (float)uv[0]; vtx.v = (float)uv[1];
        vtx.u = 1 - vtx.u; vtx.v = 1 - vtx.v;
```

What I do, can we solve this problem??
Please Answer to me

Comment: Remove the vtx.u = 1 - vtx.u; part. The other part is okay since openGL's uv's are bottom-to-top and most others are top-to-bottom.

Answer (score 1):

```
vtx.u = 1 - vtx.u; vtx.v = 1 - vtx.v;
```

Are you sure of this part ? The texture seems to be upside-down on the screen shot. The model looks mirrored as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
vtx.v = 1 - vtx.v;
```

But there is no need to

```
vtx.u = 1 - vtx.u;
```

Reference
http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/fbx-sdk/uvw-coordinates-are-importing-upside-down/m-p/4179680#M3489